# Can a method be abstract but not virtual?

Tags: c#

As I understand it, a method being marked abstract is implicitly virtual. The reason: Suppose the compile-time type of a given object is abstract. If one of the object's abstract methods is being called, the actual method to be executed is the one defined in the object's runtime type. Isn't it? If I'm right then the abstract method behaves as if it is also virtual.

In spite of that, I have successfully marked a C# method both abstract and virtual simultaneously:

```
public abstract virtual void crazy();
```

I suppose it means that an abstract method is not necessarily virtual and  being abstract is actually orthogonal to being virtual.

What do I get wrong? How can an abstract method not be virtual?

Comment: `a C# method can be declared both abstract and virtual simultaneously` false

Comment: @Romoku Every `abstract` method is virtual, you just can't add the `virtual` keyword. So I don't consider that sentence wrong.

Comment: Perhaps you meant that the class is abstract but the method is virtual?

Comment: An abstract method is a virtual method without implementation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I think the ambiguity stems from the word "declared" - is it declaring by explicitly writing the keyword, or declaring as in declaring the method in general? Or, is it *declaring a method* that is both abstract and virtual, or declaring a given method *as* such?

Comment: @CodesInChaos A method cannot be declared `abstract virtual`

Comment: Instead of using "declared" use "marked". That should be a bit more obvious as to what is meant and is in line with the wording of the compiler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot mark a method as both `abstract` and `virtual`. It will result in a compiler error:

> The abstract method 'Namespace.Class.Foo()' cannot be marked virtual

The rest of your question is correct: `abstract` methods are implicitly `virtual`.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

- An abstract method is implicitly a virtual method.
- Abstract method declarations are only permitted in abstract classes.
- Because an abstract method declaration provides no actual implementation, there is no method body; the method declaration simply ends with a semicolon and there are no braces ({ }) following the signature.
- The implementation is provided by an overriding method, which is a member of a non-abstract class.
- It is an **error** to use the **static** or **virtual** modifiers in an abstract method declaration.

Comment: `The implementation is provided by an overriding method, which is a member of a non-abstract class.`

- This is not actually true. An abstract method can be overridden in an abstract class. For example:


`public abstract class A
    {
        public abstract void Foo();
    }

    public abstract class B : A
    {
        public override void Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B.Foo()");
        }
    }`

Answer (score 2):

"You cannot use the virtual modifier with the static, abstract, private, or override modifiers."

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4(v=vs.100).aspx